# How to get file extension correctly in C++? Windows Platform

Tags: c++, file

There are many posts and answers to this question on this site, however no one can offer something worth.

One of the most popular solutions is **to get file extension from a string**. 
For example, if I had a string **"myFile.dot".** The result of getting extension would be *".dot"*, however, this actually can also be a folder, not a file, can't it?
How would the function recognize that?

Another case, if I had a file with the extension **".jfhdj"** for example, which actually doesn't exist, how should I handle it?

Concerning the **boost::filesystem file extension**. As far as I google it, it can get one specific file extension, but not any. I mean this function

```
boost::filesystem::path folder(boost::filesystem::current_path());
for (boost::filesystem::directory_iterator it(folder), end; 
     it != end; ++it)
{
    auto ext = it->path().extension();
    if (ext == ".jpeg")
    {
        std::cout << "is jpeg" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Could you tell me please if **struct stat** can give me the file extension as one of the attributes, or is there any WINAPI function that can get the file extension not from a string. Or what would you personally advice? Hope to hear from you soon. Thank you.

Comment: In what sense does a file extension "not exist"? It's not like there's a law on the books that says which combinations of characters are legal extensions.

Comment: You seem to be combining multiple problems into one. First, "myfolder.ext", where that names a directory, still has an extension of "ext" -- determining if something is a folder is a different problem from determining the extension of a file, and a folder is merely a special type of file. Second, the name of a file that does not exist can still have a filename extension, so you need to separate determining the extension from determining if the file exists. Finally, a google of "struct stat" should be enough to show that not only is there no field for an extension, there's none for a name.

Comment: File extensions are just a remnant from the old days when systems needed them to categorize the file type. Now it just happens to be whatever letters comes after the last dot in the filename.

Comment: if I have a folder and in this folder there is another folder myFolder.cpp and a file myFile.cpp; How should I recognize what is what? Thank you.

Comment: Using the WIN32 API you can use the [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[`FindNextFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to iterate over files. Those functions fill in a structure with, among other things, information if the file is actually a directory or a regular file.

Comment: yes, I use that to get the files, thank you. Concerning how to determine is a file or a folder I found a very wise solution

Comment: struct stat s;
if( stat(path,&s) == 0 )
{
    if( s.st_mode & S_IFDIR )
    {
        //it's a directory
    }
    else if( s.st_mode & S_IFREG )
    {
        //it's a file
    }
    else
    {
        //something else
    }
}
else
{
    //error
}